# Make a POST request to a View from a Django static Javascript file

Tags: javascript, python, django, heroku, django-views

I'm currently making a POST request to my view on Django. I am doing this in my HTML file.

Post request:

```
class EventDetailView(DetailView):
   model = Event
   

   def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
       return xyz
```

HTML:

```
<form method="post" onsubmit="return confirm('Confirm?');">...
                                </form>
```

How can I create this post request from a static Javascript file that my HTML file interacts with instead of from the HTML File?

Comment: You could use the `fetch` API and set up a fetch post request to the url of your view as endpoint.

Comment: @JSRB would anybody on the internet be able to make that post request or only the host of the website?

Comment: Well someone would need to know the url to call the API and have required authentication. You can control access to that view using the Django authentication backend (`login_required` decorator etc.). What do you want to achieve? Obviously the static JS fill will be delivered to the client, thus the URL revealed.

Comment: @JSRB we're trying to process payments using Stripe and Apple Pay. We have a script that has a secret key that we don't want users to see in a static JS File. So I was thinking that for the part that uses the secret key we would just make a POST call to the view. But most of the payment "logic" actually happens on the front end (we know that's bad but we're just trying to move the most sensitive part to the backend) so I'm not sure authentication is possible.

Comment: well you shouldn't deliver secret keys to the client at all. Idea: Set up an isolated view in your backend that handles the secret and trigger that view within another. Keep it in the backend. Anyways, I think for payment implementation there are dozens of best practice and guides/libraries to make it in a safe way.

Comment: Right, the idea is to never have the secret key in the client at all. That's why we want to call this view. I'm having trouble calling the view from the JS File. You mentioned using fetch. So if someone saw my source code and saw I used fetch could they replicate  my API call to my own view outside of my site?

Comment: @bernardo of course, as the JS file will contain the fetch url which is your view's endpoint. Thus, do not deliver the url to the client -  search for a different approach instead

Comment: Do you have any suggestions for a possible different approach?